# Paperclip Rails 3.2.2 Not Rotating and Resizing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

Paperclip gem 3.0.4

When I use flat Paperclip definition in Model (UserDetail has an avatar):

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {:medium =>  "300x300>", : :thumb => "64x64#" }
```

All images are created in correct proportions.

When I use a custom processor through lambda ( http://www.matthuggins.com/articles/rotating-paperclip-image-attachments-in-rails ):

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :processors => [:rotator], :styles => lambda { |a| {
  :thumb => { :geometry => '64x64#', :rotation => a.instance.rotation, },
  :medium => { :geometry => '300x300>', :rotation => a.instance.rotation, },  } }
```

The image is rotated by the specified amount but all images stay at the same size and proportions as the :original.

Is :geometry the right parameter? Has this changed in later version of Paperclip (I'm unsure of the version of Paperclip used in the web example)?

Any pointers gratefully received

Regards

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one proc per style:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
  :processors => [:rotator], 
  :styles => {
    :thumb =>  Proc.new { |a| { :geometry => '64x64#', :rotation => a.instance.rotation } },
    :medium => Proc.new { |a| { :geometry => '300x300>', :rotation => a.instance.rotation } } 
  }
```

Comment: In middle of release today. Will try first thing tomorrow. Thanks for the response

Comment: Excellent. Job done. Thanks for the time and help Victor. Regards, Peter